# How to normalize multiple y values when read TFRecord dataset

Tags: python, keras

I generate training data, all in original value, I want to normalize data when reading TFRecord dataset. First step I read all original value from training data, and loop through each iter to concatenate array, use minmaxscaler to fit train data and get scaler.

2nd step I write a normalize function to transform all data, code as below:

```
def normalizeY(inputs, targets):
    targets['Y1'] = scaler_Y1.transform(tf.cast(targets['Y1'], tf.float32))
    targets['Y2'] = scaler_Y2.transform(tf.cast(targets['Y2'], tf.float32))
    targets['Y3'] = scaler_Y3.transform(tf.cast(targets['Y3'], tf.float32))
        
    return inputs, targets
    
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
dataset = dataset.map(normalizeY)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

but the step `dataset.map(normalizeY)` gives error: `TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Answer (score 0):

I work out a solution to use min/max value to normalize instead of using scaler to transform.

```
def normalizeY(inputs, targets):
   targets['Y1'] = (tf.cast(targets['Y1'], tf.float32) - Y1_min) / (Y1_max - Y1_min)
   targets['Y2'] = (tf.cast(targets['Y2'], tf.float32) - Y2_min) / (Y2_max - Y2_min)
   targets['Y3'] = (tf.cast(targets['Y3'], tf.float32) - Y3_min) / (Y3_max - Y3_min)
```